# Spring boot @Autowire with Inheritance

Tags: spring-boot, autowired

Can somebody help me with spring boot and explain where is a problem in code, when I try to use `@Autowired` Service in `SomeTask` class I get NPE. I already try few solutions from another topics but result the same.

```
  public class Task {

    public Task() {
    }

    public void test(){

    }
}
public class SecondTask extends Task {

    @Autowired
    SomeService someService;

    public SecondTask() {
    }

    @Override
    public void test() {
        someService.exec();
    }
}

@Service
public class SomeService {


    public void exec(){

        System.out.println("works");
    }

    public SomeService() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share logs?

Comment: where do you get NPE and is SecondTask a spring bean or standalone class

Comment: Just to confirm - a. `SomeService` is an inner class of `Task` (that is what it looks like from the posted code); b. How do you create instances of `SecondTask`?

Comment: Task task = new SecondTask();
  task.test();

Comment: logs : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Don't create new instances yourself, that will create an instance outside the scope of Spring and as such will not be autowired. You have to either manually inject the dependencies or make everything spring managed and use auto wiring to inject all dependencies.

Comment: put your stacktrace here, is more easy to figure out what is happening.

Comment: can you try making void method static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that the SecondTask instance is not created by Spring, thus nothing will process your `@Autowired` annotation.

If you want `@Autowire` working then either you should inject the dependencies programmatically or mark your SecondTask as a Spring bean. Here you can choose from multiple scopes: singleton, prototype, etc., according to your use case.

When you have this configuration, you can easily do `appContext.getBean(SecondTask.class)` to get the actual instance of the class managed by the container.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score -1):

when you call using `new SecondTask()` Spring creates a new instance of this class with the variables(someService) being assigned with null. Hence when you calll `task.test()` it in turn calls `someService.exec()` which will lead to NPE since `someService` is null. If you want someService to be not null, then you must Autowire SecondTask and then call the function

Comment: I tried and it's still NPE, can you provide some example?